# Add form values without exceeding a total value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Excually Im not a programmer, but Im trying to learn how to make a questionnaire with html and javascript:

I have four selection boxes in a form. Each one of the selection boxes has the values through 0 to 10. The main rule of this questionnaire is to change the value of all four selection boxes so that it adds up to 10.

I figured out the following solution:

- instant updated text box where it calculates the total value selected (with onChange);
- validate at submit button if a *total value* of 10 (and not more or less) is selected.

Alternatively I would even assign a (error) message instantly when the user selects a value that exceeds the *total value* of 10.

I have some half baked javascripts, but I don't have enough understanding of the subject to excually connect the dots. Hope you can help me.

Tim

My framework:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function editTotalValue(){

}

function  validateTotalValue(){

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<select name="question1" onChange="editTotalValue();">
  <option selected value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="question2" onChange="editTotalValue();">
  <option selected value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="question3" onChange="editTotalValue();">
  <option selected value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="question4" onChange="editTotalValue();">
  <option selected value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<!-- Show total value selected in text box -->
<input name="totalValue" type="text" maxlength="2" readonly="true">
<!-- Validate that totalValue(); is indeed 10 and not more or less and pass on the data -->
<input name="submit" type="button" onClick="validateTotalValue();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the complete question solved yourself? What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something more in-depth that you can play with:

```
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = checkTarget;

function checkTarget(evt)
{
    var el;  
    if(window.event)
    {
        //checking for IE equivalent
        el = window.event.srcElement;  
    }else if(evt.target)
    {
        el = evt.target;       
    }
    if(window.event)
    {
        //checking for IE equivalent
        window.event.returnValue = false;   
    }else if(evt.preventDefault)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();   
    }
    calculateValues(el);
}

function calculateValues(form)
{
    var values = [];
    var value = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<form.elements.length;i++)
    {
        var el = form.elements[i];
        if(el.tagName === "SELECT")
        {
            values.push(el.value);   
        }
    }
    for(var j=0;j<values.length;j++)
    {
        value = value + parseInt(values[j], 10);
    }
    updateValue(value);
    checkValue(values, value);
}

function updateValue(value)
{
     document.getElementById("result_box").value = value;             
}

function checkValue(values, value)
{
    var temp = [];
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
    {
        if(values[i] > 0 && values[i] < 10)
        {
            temp.push(values[i]);
        }  
    }
    if(value === 10 && temp.length === 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("message_box").value = "You win!";
    }else if(value > 10 && temp.length === 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("message_box").value = "Value is more than 10";  
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YS6mm/9/

Tested as working in: Firefox 4, IE8, IE8 Compatibility View (Quirks), IE7 Quirks Mode, Chrome 4, Safari 4, and Opera 11.

Comment: Hi, Great script! Thanks for the link, that helped a lot to figure out how it works. 


At html level:

Comment: But How would I do an instant update. An onChange to call all the script so that message_box would be updated anytime a user changes the selectionbox?

Comment: Wow amazing! Thank you! It exactly how I wanted it. However, now the submit button doesnt work. I learned from your code. I changed the el.submit by executing a function sumbitCheck. But somehow, it always gives a negative and then resets the form. http://jsfiddle.net/triggerload/XHWwg/3/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if you wanted to use the submit button. Here's a version with the submit button fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/YS6mm/18/

Comment: thanks, it worked out perfectly! Im learning a lot :D Im am trying to solve how I can make two of those forms but with one button to check whether each total 10 and if true to give an success alert. Im playing for hours but with your code I cannot succeed. Can you tell me if this is easy or that it's better to pose different/other question. Anyways, Thanks Matt for your devotion to help people like me :)

Comment: See here my result. Without Matt I wouldn't have come this far :)
http://jsfiddle.net/triggerload/XHWwg/42/

btw, if you would reload the page, it would remember the value selected right?

Comment: Hi Matt, making a lot of progress with your code. But can you explain this: var selects = grabFormSelects(holder, "valueList"); ---> it somehow grabs the class but how would I change it for the ID's?

Comment: I avoided using ids because it's easier to grab by class name. If you know the ids, you can try passing them as an array and then checking against them in a for loop.

Comment: Ok, I will leave it, as I found another solution without changing things. Altough, do you know why I can't put a DIV around a select attribute? If I do, the value will pass to the resultbox, but doesnt update?  weird...  http://jsfiddle.net/triggerload/XHWwg/159/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616736/putting-a-div-around-a-select-attribute-is-equal-to-trouble-why

Answer (score 1):

```
function editTotalValue() {
   var val = 0;
   for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
       val = val + document.getElementById("question" + i).value;
   }

   var display = document.getElementbyId("totalValue");

   if (val > 10) {
       alert("error");
   } else {
       display.value = val;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a little different - if they select a box and that selection makes the total value > 10 then it throws an alert immediately.

Comment: Thank you! Learned a lot from it!