# Putting a DIV around a SELECT attribute is equal to trouble, why?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, html

I am a javascript learner. I have a little script that is almost finished. I just want to put DIV's around the html select attribute. If I do that, my script won't work. Why? Is this forbidden?

http://jsfiddle.net/triggerload/XHWwg/159/

```
    <div id="test">
      <select class="valueList" name="n1">
        <option selected value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me... You will have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: From W3 Schools:
Note: Browsers usually place a line break before and after the div element.

Comment: @Acolyte Not so much a line break, just the element has *block* display and therefore consumes all horizontal space by default.

Comment: If you want your code to be semantically valid, try adding a `fieldset` instead of a `div` around your selects since they're form elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem almost certainly has to do with the way you are trying to grab the `select` element:

```
function grabFormSelects(parent, class_name)
{
    //make new array to hold nodes
    var nodes = [];
    for(var i=0;i<parent.childNodes.length;i++)
    {
        var node = parent.childNodes[i];
        //filter out any node that isn't an element node and doesn't have the class name we're looking for
        if(node.nodeType === 1 && node.className === class_name)
        {
            nodes.push(node);
        }   
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

You're checking only for direct child nodes of `question_holder`, but when you add your `div` the `select` element is no longer a direct child of `question_holder`, it is a child of the `div` that you added.  So of course it does not get returned by your `grabFormSelect()` code.

As a quick fix, you can try:

```
function isDescendent(node, parent) {
    //see if any of the nodes ancestors match the specified parent node
    while (node.parentNode && node.parentNode != parent) {
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return node.parentNode == parent;
}

function grabFormSelects(parent, class_name)
{
    //make new array to hold nodes
    var nodes = [];
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++)
    {
        var node = selects[i];
        //filter out any node that isn't an element node and doesn't have the class name we're looking for
        if(node.nodeType === 1 && node.className === class_name && isDescendent(node, parent))
        {
            nodes.push(node);
        }   
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: aha, I see. Unfortunately I have no way of getting around this. How would it be possible grab the select immediately. Something with if(el.tagName === "SELECT" && el.name === n1 || el.name === n2 and so on..?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is because parent is no longer question_holder.  It is now the id of the div.

```
function addListeners()
{
    var holder = document.getElementById("question_holder");
    var selects = grabFormSelects(holder, "valueList");
    var holder2 = document.getElementById("question_holder2");
    var selects2 = grabFormSelects(holder2, "valueList2");
    for(var i=0;i<selects.length;i++)
    {
        selects[i].onchange = checkTarget;   
    }
    for(var i=0;i<selects2.length;i++)
    {
        selects2[i].onchange = checkTarget2;   
    }
}

function grabFormSelects(parent, class_name)
{
    //make new a
```

So holder should now call document.getElementById("test")

Comment: thanks for taking a look at it! learned a lot from your comment!